# Disable specific jQuery draggable out of many after that specific item has been dropped

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, droppable

I'm trying to use jQuery draggable and droppable to compare results of a search. Basically, I am limiting the compare to 5 items. So, I have 5 droppable boxes and a number of draggable images that will go into those boxes. I am trying to ensure that when a droppable box is full it cant be refilled and the item that was dragged into it can not be dragged again. The draggable item reverts to a disabled state. I've managed to disable the last dropped item, but the second result can't be dragged at all. So, my question is: **How can I disable dragging for a specific image after that image has been dropped, and still allow other results to be put into the remaining boxes?** Also, the filled droppable div should not be able to contain more than one image. There is alot of code involved so, you can find a demo here http://jsfiddle.net/SeasonEnds/VNzrB/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple elements with the ID of `productimage`. All I did was change each instance of `id="productimage"` to `class="productimage"` and then changed your JS to select based on class rather than by ID. When a browser looks for an element by ID, once it's found, the browser stops looking because it's assumed that each ID is unique:

```
var $gallery = $(".productimage"),
```

...

```
accept: ".productimage > .icon",
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/VNzrB/1/

That will make it so each of the `draggable` elements will be drag-able. To make it so you can only place a single `draggable` in a `droppable` element, you can disable each `droppable` element as something is dropped into it:

```
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        deleteImage(ui.helper);
        $(ui.draggable).draggable('disable');

        //disable the droppable element that just had a draggable dropped into it
        $(this).droppable('disable');
    }
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/VNzrB/3/

### Update

To only change the height/width of the cloned `draggable` helper, you can target it with: `$(ui.helper).css(...);`.

Change:

```
    start: function() {

        $(".myCheckbox").prop("checked", true);
        $(".ui-draggable").not(this).css({
            height: 50,
            width: 50
        });
    },
```

To:

```
    start: function(event, ui) {

        $(".myCheckbox").prop("checked", true);
        $(ui.helper).css({
            height: 50,
            width: 50
        });
    }
```

Note that you have to

See this update in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/VNzrB/4/

Comment: Basic stuff. Thanks for recognizing that. I resize my image upon dragging to fit those boxes. I've noticed that your solution causes all images to be re-sized upon dragging of one image. Should I target a specific ui-draggable by id to fix the css?? How would you go about doing that?

Comment: @SeasonEnds See the **update** to my answer. You can target the correct element by accessing the `ui` object that's passed into the `start` function.